Scattering by point potentials
Suppose we consider the quantum scattering of two particles. The interaction Hamiltonian is given by:
$$H = -\Delta_{\vec{x}}-\Delta_{\vec{y}} +V(x-y)$$
where $V$ is the interaction potential between the particles. In the center of mass reference frame, we have $\vec{R} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}+\vec{y})$ and $\vec{r} = \vec{x}-\vec{y}$. The Schrödinger equation, in this case, becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta_{\vec{R}}\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) +2\Delta_{\vec{r}}\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) = E\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}).$$
We assume separable solutions $\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) = \varphi(\vec{R})f(\vec{r})$. Writting $E = E_{\vec{R}}+E_{\vec{r}}$, then we conclude:
$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta_{\vec{R}}\varphi(\vec{R})=E_{\vec{R}}\varphi(\vec{R})$$
and
$$(-2\Delta_{\vec{r}} +V(\vec{r}))f(\vec{r})=E_{\vec{r}}f(\vec{r}).$$
Setting $E_{\vec{R}} = \frac{1}{2}|\vec{P}|^{2}$ and $E_{\vec{r}} = \frac{1}{2}|\vec{p}|^{2}$ for simplicity, we obtain $\varphi(\vec{R}) = e^{i\frac{1}{2}\langle \vec{P},\vec{R}\rangle}$ and $f$ is behaves asymptotically as:
$$f(\vec{r}) \approx e^{2\pi i\langle \vec{p},\vec{r}\rangle}-\frac{C}{|\vec{r}|}e^{2\pi i |\vec{p}||\vec{r}|}.$$
Putting it altogether, we obtain an asymptotic expansion for $\psi$:
$$\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) \approx e^{i\frac{1}{2}\langle \vec{P},\vec{R}\rangle}\bigg{(}e^{2\pi i\langle \vec{p},\vec{r}\rangle}-\frac{C}{|\vec{r}|}e^{2\pi i |\vec{p}||\vec{r}|}\bigg{)}.$$
In many cases, one considers scattering processes at low energies, in such a way that $\frac{1}{2}(|\vec{P}|^{2}+|\vec{p}|^{2}) \approx 0$, so the above expression becomes:
$$f(\vec{r}) \approx e^{2\pi i\langle \vec{p},\vec{r}\rangle}-\frac{C}{|\vec{r}|}e^{2\pi i |\vec{p}||\vec{r}|}.$$
Putting it altogether, we obtain an asymptotic expansion for $\psi$:
$$\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) \approx 1-\frac{C}{|\vec{r}|}.$$
My question is: suppose we don't want to assume low energy processes but, instead, a scattering process in which the potential $V$ has a really small range, that is, there is some small radius $r_{0}$ in which $V$ is not zero. Does the solution:
$$\psi(\vec{R},\vec{r}) \approx 1-\frac{C}{|\vec{r}|}$$
also hold in this regime? Otherwise, in which regime this approximation can be considered if we don't want to consider low energy states?

Your interaction potential has disappeared. At high energies, the binding energy of the electron to its atom can be neglected. And you would have to grapple with the notorious difficulty of reduced mass formalism in SR; I don't think you have implemented it correctly as you have presented it here anyway. Your asymptotic expansion makes no sense either.

Indeed... was it your intention to neglect the interaction potential $V(x-y)$ in what you write? Then you shouldn't call it scattering and your question becomes simply one about free particles...

Guys, sorry. This was a typo. The interaction potential is there, I will edit the post.

Now it looks right. The asymptotic expansion for $f$ now comes from the fact that I am considering short range $V$, so at large $|\vec{r}|$ we have $V \approx 0$.
